# I am receiving status code 200 but fail fail function fire on completion

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am inspecting my code using fire bug ,i receive ajax response from server with 200 status code but fail function call on completion, the desired function call is  done(function (){})

```
 function get_data(l)
    {
        myurl="http://localhost/qasim/outlets/home_controller/get_pros/"+l;
        //console.log(myurl);
        $.ajax({
            url:myurl,
            type:'GET',
            dataType:'JSON'

        }).done(function(data){alert(data);}).fail(function(data){alert("fail");});

        //$.get(myurl).done(function(data){alert(data);});
    }

    $(function (){
        $(window).scroll(function (e){
            get_data(4);
        //  console.log(window.pageYOffset);

        });
    });
```

Comment: Ok, so you know it is failing. Do you know WHY it is failing? if you're getting back a 200, my best guess is your json isn't valid json, but since you didn't log the arguments of the fail callback or provide sample result data all we can do is guess.

Comment: Thank its done, there was some commented text in result .

Answer (score -1):

Change your `fail(data)` callback to use

`fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});`

The `textStatus` and `errorThrown` values will indicate the error that occurred.